# Checking out a file from SVN

Tags: svn

I have a file that I checked out from SVN and now after few changes I checked it back in. The question I am working on this file all the time. if I check the file in and start editing it locally, Will it affect during the build process?.

TU

Comment: SVN by default does not have a checkout-checkin operation. Make sure you understand svn and don't assume its just like other systems.

Comment: If the build process is done with the working copy where you work all the time, it will use the file with modifications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your build process involves checking out or exporting the code from your Subversion repository into production, having local (uncommitted) modifications to the file you are working on won't affect the code in the repository.

However, if you continue working on the file as a working copy, you should not commit your changes if the file is itself in a non-working state, or in a state that would cause other components in the repository to fail.  Only commit when your code works or won't negatively affect anything else involved in the build.

When there is a large amount of work to be done on an area of the codebase that will be under development for a while, the more appropriate action is often to create a branch rather than to work on the trunk directly.

Now if your build is done from your local working copy rather than the central repository, your local changes will affect the build.

#### Update:

You seem to misunderstand how Subversion handles checkout and commit.  Unless your repository is setup to lock a checked out file, where others would not be able to commit to that file, the repository does not keep track of what has been checked out. It will not care if you have not committed changes -- the build will work from what is current in the repository without regard to any local modifications you have.

Comment: I keep updating the file with modifications and I also work in a branch. Can I checkout the file after I check-in since I have to work on it?. If we push the build would it complain that the file is checked out or it will pick the file that was checked-in last?

Comment: @Giri After you check in (commit) a file, the copy you were editing (your working copy) can be committed again when you are ready. You can delete it then checkout a new copy as well.